# Puppet Apache2 isn't loading php module

Tags: php, apache, development-environment, puppet, provisioning

I'm very new to puppet and I tried the last hours to get a development environment working.

Currently im using example42s apache and php module, the provision is successful but the apache2 server isn't using the php module.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Puppet 2.7.11, Apache 2.22 and php 5.5

```
$ php -v
```

is returning successfully the version.

```
## index.html
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

return nothing,

My default.pp

```
Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }

exec { 'apt-get update':
  command => 'apt-get update',
  timeout => 60,
  tries   => 3
}

class { 'apt':
  always_apt_update => true,
}

package { ['python-software-properties']:
  ensure  => 'installed',
  require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

$sysPackages = [ 'build-essential', 'git', 'curl']
package { $sysPackages:
  ensure => "installed",
  require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

## Apache
class { "apache": }
apache::module { 'rewrite': }
apache::vhost { 'devbox.example.com':
    docroot => '/var/www/devbox.example.com',
    port => 80,
}

# PHP
apt::ppa { 'ppa:ondrej/php5':
  before  => Class['php'],
}
class { 'php': }
$phpModules = [ 'curl', 'mysql', 'cli', 'intl']
php::module { $phpModules: }
php::ini { 'php':
  value   => ['date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"'],
  target  => 'php.ini',
  service => 'apache',
}
```

To get started with puppet I followed this tutorial
http://www.erikaheidi.com/blog/a-begginers-guide-to-vagrant-getting-your-portable-development-e

any suggestions why apache isn't loading the php mod ?

Comment: PHP is "64bit" or "32bit"?

Comment: If you are unsure whether the PHP is "64bit" then download the module for "64bit" too.

Comment: I dont find any only 64bit php modules for puppet, however php is working on the server, only the connection the apache service is not working

Comment: Apache not work? After install module? Read log error (php and apache).

Comment: apache is working, if tested with a simple index.html in the vhost

Comment: I've read the logs, motly they are empty, no errors

Comment: Are you sure the "php.ini" is configured correctly (maybe the path of php.ini is the other path)

Comment: what do you mean with "is the other path" ?

Comment: "php.ini" may be coming from somewhere else. In my case the file "php.ini" is not in `/php/` folder, but in `/apache/bin` (this is only just a theory)

Comment: so apache may looks for the wrong php.ini ?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but if memory serves, `mod_php` will **not** respect `<?php` tags in `.html` files in the default configuration. Have you tried `index.php`?

Comment: fixed it, finally :) !

Comment: And how did you do that ?